# Comma Separated values in json array are treated as delimiters

Tags: java, json, org.json

I am parsing a json file that contains values that are comma separated.

Such as {"values":[{"key":"some, value", "key2":"somevalue"}]}

When parsing this using the org.json library it is using the commas in the first key as a delimiter so it is parsing them as separate objects.

```
JSONTokener tokener = new JSONTokener(new FileReader(someJsonFile));

JSONObject a = new JSONObject(tokener);

//I believe the problem is occuring here
JSONArray values = (JSONArray) instruments.get("values");
```

I want the values that include commas to be treated as one value. Instead of being parsed into 'some' and 'value', i want it to be 'some, value' as indicated in the file.

Comment: how do you get values into `instruments`? the code sample does not show that

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Answer (score -1):

You should create a POJO class that is equivalent to the JSon String format. Then you can use jackson to convert the JSon string to pojo objects. It will not have the mentioned issue.

Reference : https://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-convert-java-object-to-from-json-jackson/

Comment: While the link might have the necessary components for an answer, it's best if you include the relevant bits into your answer so that it is self-sustained.  Without it, If the link goes down, the answer becomes less useful